# How to add menu command handler in VC 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

how to add a menu command handler in vc 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a trick question?

[alt text http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/5603/93284930.png](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/5603/93284930.png)